# Reverse count with paginated entries?

Tags: pagination, forloop, count

I have this loop

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('sermons').limit('10') as pageInfo, entries %}

        {% for sermon in entries %}
        ...
        {{ loop.revindex }}
        ...
        {% endfor %}
```

That outputs a count from 10 to 1 - however, there's more entries than just the 10.

How can I output the count of what would be absolute total results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already pass the array keys into the loop as a variable `pageInfo`. There's a couple of properties you can access from it, see the Craft docs:

[Templating Reference → `{% paginate %}`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/paginate#the-pageInfo-variable)

Of interest for you is probably these:

> `pageInfo.total` – The total number of elements across all pages
>   `pageInfo.currentPage` – The current page number.

It looks like there's no property for the "current element number" and you need to do some math to output it:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.limit(10) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}    
    {% for entry in pageEntries %}

        {% set index = (pageInfo.currentPage - 1) * 10 + loop.index0 %}

        {{ pageInfo.total - index }} of
        {{ pageInfo.total }}

    {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

Comment: No dice on the 2nd page of paginated entries with that update. 1st entry on that page shows 211 when it should be 171

Comment: Did you adjust the numbers? I tested the solution and it worked on my install...

Comment: Doh! My limit was different after trying something else

Answer (score -1):

```
{% set sermons = craft.entries.section('sermons').limit(null) %}

{{ sermons|length }}
```

By default, the `.find()` method, which is what gets called when you call `craft.entries` automatically gets limited to 100. Get round that by using `.limit(null)`

Comment: I don't want to display them all though, they need pagination. I have 221 entries so I want to count each down from 221 to 1